# Persistent Desktop Icons?

Tags: windows, icons, desktop

Deciding to clean up and organize my file system hierarchy, there has been an interesting feature for some of the icons located on the desktop that I wish to know more about.

If you ever move your desktop location, via a program or manually from file explorer, you will notice that the new folder system is loaded but the desktop maintains certain icons like the recycling bin, a web browser, or a shortcut to some other installed program. However I can not find documentation on what this feature is and how to manipulate it to my own needs.

I would like to know what this feature is and how to change it so I can have **desired** applications persist in between desktop changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ah i knew this was something i forgot about. How these things maintain inside the desktop is based upon whats located in the public desktop found in

```
C:\Users\Public\Desktop
```

It is a hidden folder so it would need to be enabled by the file explorer before this thing can be utilized.

Comment: Everything in the Public user folder is shared amonst all users on your computer. When you install a program and select: "Install for all users" its start menu icons and desktop icons will be placed in the public user space rather than your own.

Comment: However if you were to change desktops as where the working folder is referred to, the public desktops contents will still be there. Think of the desktop containing 3 sources. The first source is anything the particular user has done to the desktop such as file or folder containers. The second source is the public desktop which holds all apps that are mandated to be on all users. The third source is the stuff that cant be modified, like the recycle bin which is usually hardcoded to remain on the desktop at  all times. All three sources are loaded when an interaction or change had been made.